# Image gallery doesn't load at page load, performance issue with purechat

Tags: javascript, performance

I am using the nivoSlider image gallery on my website, however when the page loads the gallery doesn't appear straight away. And after a little while it loads

Using firebug I have identified it is an issue with including pure chat in my website. If I remove pure chat from my code it loads soon as the page starts. How can I make is so pure chat doesn't affect the load of the image gallery (without removing it from my page)?

With purechat
[image: firebug including purechat]

Without purechat
[image]

Comment: Load pure chat after all the elements are loaded. in other words, on `$(window).load` rather than `$(function(){..});`

Comment: still a little flicker every now and then, but that did the trick. Just updated the php include code with $(window).load and it works great: $(window).load(function () { var done = false; var script = document.createElement("script"); script.async = true; script.type = "text/javascript"; script.src = "https://www.purechat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetScript"..........................

Comment: great. I am glad it worked. The flicker would be due to the div not initialized yet